# Looking for the exact config.xml location for PHPUnit testing in Magento

Tags: phpunit, magento-1.7

I'm currently trying to get PHPUnit working with together with Magento. On some places in the web people recommend the extension from EcomDev so I tried it out.

I build an example setup like written in [this tutorial](http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/02/01/phpunit-and-magento-yes-you-can.html), I just replaced EcomDev_Example_... with Test_JustTest_...

However, it doesn't work as it should and I guess I put the data in the wrong config.xml. At the moment I've written down the module name in /app/code/local/Test/JustTest/etc/config.xml and in the config.xml of the extension to just try something different. Well, I can run PHPUnit but it always tells me that there's no test to run.

I spent a lot of time on Google not finding a more detailed example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im faced with the same problem, but now I get it worked.
I created **app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml** with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <phpunit>
        <suite>
            <modules>
                <Namespace_Module/>
            </modules>
        </suite>
    </phpunit>
    <modules>
        <namespace_module>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </namespace_module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eav>
                <rewrite>
                    <entity_increment_numeric>Namespace_Module_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric</entity_increment_numeric>
                </rewrite>
            </eav>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

In fact the name of these are not Namespace_Module, I just replaced to show you. Its a module that overrides numeric model from magento, but it has no big differences.

See that my test is under
**app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Test/Model/Entity/Increment/Numeric.php**

And looks like:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Test_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case
{

    /**
    * Test Next Id Never Returns zero
    *
    * @test
    */
    public function testGetNextIdNeverReturnsZero(){   
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

After all set, you should run your tests using the following command on console/terminal:

> phpunit UnitTests.php

Remember that you should enable your module by adding Namespace_Module.xml at app/etc/modules as any other model. My mistake was that i named the folder as Tests instead of Test in my model. I dont think you are doing the same thing...

Anyway, I hope it helps. For more information, [the manual](http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/05/24/ecomdev_phpunit-manual-version-0-2-0-is-available-for-download.html) could help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It has been a while and the problem is no longer current but your answer sounds fine so I accepted it. Thanks again! Will keep that in mind when I face such stuff again. :)